# $next_avail ID - a sort of auto_increment I need for my website - speed of the query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a **portal** / large website and I have a question as to how to optimise my mySql / PDO queries in a special case.

I developed it this way : when I'm inserting an iD (unique / primary) I do the following code to find out the highest **unused** id in a *specific* table, and then do an **INSERT** with that id ($next_avail).

After a short chat last days on *stackoverflow* I got the ideea that AUTO_INCREMENT is best for this action.

But now, I realize that in most of the cases I also use $next_avail (the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT how it would be) to insert in other tables as a column, as well.

So my code makes sense for these inserts.

My question is, how would this code below work for millions of rows as speed, for each insert I do depends on it.

Please write comments and ask me to clarify what is not clear for you, in this question.

Thanks, Adrian

```
$next_avail = 1 ;
                    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT news_id from mya_news ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 1");
                    $stmt->execute();
                    while ( list($id) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) ) {                                                   
                        $next_avail = $id + 1;
                    }
```

Comment: It would be terribly inaccurate for start, making it totally unusable for what you want it to do.

Comment: Your premise is wrong - you can never know what the next number generated by `auto_increment` will be. First off - you are incrementing the last ID by 1. MySQL can be set up to increment the auto_increments by a different offset. Second - say you got number 10 as your possible next_id. An insert occurs that should generate number 10, but something goes wrong, transaction fails and the number is not used, next one in line will be 11. You calculated that next in line is 10, but in reality you got a different number. Welcome to lost and inaccurate references world.

Comment: Take the second case. Two PHP processes (2 requests) query the db for next_id. Both obtain that next_id should be 10. Meanwhile, during the phase between sending the data to PHP from the executed query, another process inserts a record (or more of them), thus making your calculation invalid. You'd calculate that next_id is 11, when in reality it could be 500, especially if you have millions of inserts/reads/whatever.

Comment: MySQL does actually store the next auto increment id in one of its system tables. However except under very exceptional circumstances it is probably best to not even think about trying to use that.

Comment: Yes, MySQL does that, not PHP. MySQL is the only process that can accurately say what the next_id MIGHT be. I'm saying MIGHT because that number doesn't actually have to be used (because an insert might fail). Also, if many different processes depend on that number - that implies a design that's completely faulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do that, just use an auto_increment in your table, and also use the PHP functions to get the last_inserted_id `mysql_insert_id()`

take a look to this sites:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

this one is with PDO
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: So what you are saying is that it's perfectly fine to calculate what the next AUTO_INCREMENT might be using PHP?

Comment: i think i was wrong, so far I was testing the whole thing alone, but I will stick NOW to AUTO_INCREMENT and the PDO function that returns the last insert_id

Comment: The idea of having next_id is just wrong, whatever you do to obtain that number will be futile the first time something goes wrong and things do go wrong constantly.

Comment: also, i have another situation where there's a transaction_id which increments too but does not behave like a primary_key AUTO_iNCREMENT...there can be more rows of the same transaction_id...i believe i can do a MAX(transaction_id)+1 for a new transaction_id field to increase it with 1 since only one particular account at a time can increase it....right ?

Comment: @AdrianTanase you can't have 2 auto_increments in one table, my best suggestion would be create a trigger to auto increment your transactions:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html

Comment: @AdrianTanase - or have a transaction table with transaction_id being the autonumber primary key. Insert a row to this and retrieve the id using mysql_insert_id().

Comment: oh well, the way my transaction_id works in my website is that only 1 person at a time can initialize a NEW transaction_id of the id that corresponds to the user. There are concurrent users, true, but transaction_id = 3 is different for each user :) so all good

Answer (score 2):

Possibly use max rather than ordering the results and using a limit.

However this is very risky. A chance that 2 bits of processing will both get the same $next_avail at the same time. I would suggest changing the order you insert rows (or even inserting a dummy row to get the next id, and updating the row later on) to use the AUTO_INCREMENT column value